# Getting rows from a given valeue of cells in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

l have a dataframe as follow :

```
print(df.head(15))

     0     5     6      7     8       9
0  NaN  char  left  right   top  bottom
1    0     m    38    104  2456    2492
2    1     i    40    102  2442    2448
3    2     i    40    100  2402    2410
4    3     l    40    102  2372    2382
5    4     m    40    102  2312    2358
6    5     u    40    102  2292    2310
7    6     i    40    104  2210    2260
8    7     l    40    104  2180    2208
9    8     i    40    104  2140    2166
10   9     l    40    104  2124    2134
11  10     .   203    213   191     198
12  11     3   235    262   131     198
13  12     A   275    347   147     239
14  13     M   363    465   145     239
```

l want to retrieve rows given a value of a cell.
for instance if l give `m` l got the following :

```
1    0     m    38    104  2456    2492
5    4     m    40    102  2312    2358
```

if l give  `left=40` and `right=102`

l get

```
2    1     i    40    102  2442    2448
4    3     l    40    102  2372    2382
5    4     m    40    102  2312    2358
6    5     u    40    102  2292    2310
```

Comment: For the record, here are the docs related to selecting data http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first clean dataframe - from first row create columns and then remove this row:

```
#columns from first row 
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
#remove 0 from column names
df.columns.name = None
#reove first row and first column, create default index (0,1,2,...)
df = df.iloc[1:, 1:].reset_index(drop=True)
cols = ['left','right','top','bottom']
#convert string columns to int
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)
print (df)
   char  left  right   top  bottom
0     m    38    104  2456    2492
1     i    40    102  2442    2448
2     i    40    100  2402    2410
3     l    40    102  2372    2382
4     m    40    102  2312    2358
5     u    40    102  2292    2310
6     i    40    104  2210    2260
7     l    40    104  2180    2208
8     i    40    104  2140    2166
9     l    40    104  2124    2134
10    .   203    213   191     198
11    3   235    262   131     198
12    A   275    347   147     239
13    M   363    465   145     239
```

and then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df[df['char'] == 'm']
print (m)
  char  left  right   top  bottom
0    m    38    104  2456    2492
4    m    40    102  2312    2358

df1 = df[(df['left'] == 40) & (df['right'] == 102)]
print (df1)
  char  left  right   top  bottom
1    i    40    102  2442    2448
3    l    40    102  2372    2382
4    m    40    102  2312    2358
5    u    40    102  2292    2310
```

But if dont need data cleaning:

```
m = df[df['5'] == 'm']
print (m)
     0  5   6    7     8     9
1  0.0  m  38  104  2456  2492
5  4.0  m  40  102  2312  2358

df1 = df[(df['6'] == '40') & (df['7'] == '102')]
print (df1)
     0  5   6    7     8     9
2  1.0  i  40  102  2442  2448
4  3.0  l  40  102  2372  2382
5  4.0  m  40  102  2312  2358
6  5.0  u  40  102  2292  2310
```

Comment: Hmmm, only one answer will be accepted . And another answer does not works without data cleaning.

Comment: how can l use df1 = df[(df['6'] == '40') & (df['7'] == '102')] to print it only with column=(0,8) and columns= 5 until 7 and only with pandas index ?

Comment: it is a bit complicated, but try `df1 = df.loc[(df['6'] == '40') & (df['7'] == '102'), '0':'8'].loc[5:7]`

Comment: hmm, try `6`, `7` maybe it is integers. Check it by `print (df.columns`)

Comment: df.iloc[, [0,8]] , df.iloc[:, 5:7] actually is the solution. however priniting only pandas indexes don't know.

Comment: the solutions you suggested doesn't work when l set header=None ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe then works first solution without cleaning data.

Comment: for my problem l have to read data without header, l have to set header=none

Comment: Can you add first 5 rows of sample of file to question ?

Comment: I try test it and there is something wrong, need first rows of file `char`, `left` set to columns. Obvoiusly it working if remove `header=None`, but it depends of data.

Comment: If first row in data is `0     5     6      7     8       9` and need remove it, add parameter  `skiprows=1` for remove first row and second row is set to column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df['char']=='m']
df[(df['left']==40) & (df['right']==102)]
```

edited to include missing opening bracket. thanks.

Comment: Should be `df[(df['left']==40) & (df['right']==102)]` (each condition should be surrounded by parenthesis)